# Why am I unable to put text in my stacked bar chart (ggplot using geom_bar) without losing all of my data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I am trying to include values in my stacked bar chart (eventually I would like to show the percentages, but right now I am struggling to get even the values already in the dataframe to show up) in the actual bars to show what the numbers are and make the graphic easier to read.  When I add in "+ geom_text(aes(label = value))" the numbers appear, but cause all of the data (actual bars) to disappear.  How can I add in the values but not have my bars disappear?  And is there an easy way to put in other values to use (such as the percentages) and put them in the center?  Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)
library(ggthemes)


Percentage <- c(rep("100%", 2), rep("80%", 2), rep("60%", 2), rep("40%", 2), rep("20%", 2), rep("0%", 2), rep("NA", 2))
case_control <- rep(c("Cases","Controls"), 7)
value <- c(6, 0, 78, 9, 88, 7, 181, 365, 230, 307, 691, 1501, 2, 358)
del_df <- data.frame(Percentage, case_control, value)
del_df$Percentage <- factor(del_df$Percentage, levels = c("NA", "0%", "20%", "40%", "60%", "80%", "100%"))

ggplot(del_df, aes(fill = case_control, y = value, x = Percentage)) + geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity")  + coord_flip() + theme_classic() + labs(x = "Gene Score Evidence Level", fill = "", y = "Cumulative Findings") + ggtitle("Deletions")
```

Here is what the graph looks like with the code above:

[image]

When I add in `+ geom_text(aes(label = value))` right after the `geom_bar()` information, this is what my graph looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just need a position argument in `geom_text`:

```
library(ggplot)

ggplot(del_df, aes(fill = case_control, y = value, x = Percentage)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(position = "fill",label = value) + 
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x = "Gene Score Evidence Level", fill = "", y = "Cumulative Findings") +
  ggtitle("Deletions")
```

[image]

Or, if you prefer, you could use `position_fill()`:

```
ggplot(del_df, aes(fill = case_control, y = value, x = Percentage)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", 
           stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(position = position_fill(vjust = .5),
            label = value) + 
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x = "Gene Score Evidence Level", fill = "", y = "Cumulative Findings") +
  ggtitle("Deletions")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  Is there a way to put both values next to each other in the center of the bar (since in this case some of the segments of the bar are so small and don't seem to "fit" in the space)?